# no member function declared in class

Tags: c++, function, compilation, linker

I'm dealing with a very weird issue that I've never encountered before. Here is the code:

```
//ISerialData.h
class ISerialData
{
public:
    //snipped
    virtual unsigned int getDataSize()=0;
    //snipped
};

//CSerialData.h
class CSerialData : public ISerialData
{
private:
    //snipped
    unsigned int getDataSize();
    //snipped
};

//CSerialData.cpp
unsigned int CSerialData::getDataSize()
{
return dataStream.str().length();
}
```

Compiling it gives the error:

```
CSerialData.cpp:80: error: no ‘unsigned int CSerialData::getDataSize()’ member function declared in class ‘CSerialData’
```

Doing some trouble shooting, I removed the implementation from CSerialData.cpp to see what would happen. To my surprise, it compiled and linked successfully.

To test, I made the following statements in main.cpp:

```
//main.cpp
ISerialData* sd = new CSerialData();
int w = sd->getDataSize();
std::cout<<"W: "<<w<<"\n";
```

Which outputted the following:

```
W: -1543571782
```

If the program had the implementation, it would be zero, but I get garbage. I was expecting it to crash with a pure virtual call at least, much less link properly.

What could possibly cause it to:
1. Link at all
2. Run a function that doesn't have a definition
3. Not catch a pure virtual function call.
4. Not crash in any way

There must be *something* that it's calling, but I can't figure out how to troubleshoot this further.

This was compiled under Debian Squeeze 6.0.4 with:
g++ 4.4.5 (Debian 4.4.5-8)
ld version: GNU ld (GNU Binutils for Debian) 2.20.1-system.20100303

Any insight is most appreciated, this function is one of three that I just added to the class, all of them show the same problems.

**UPDATE: Test case works, no idea how to reproduce issue**

Test case compiles now:

```
//Interface.h

#ifndef INTERFACEH
#define INTERFACEH

class IInterface
{
public:
    virtual ~IInterface() {}
    virtual unsigned int getDataSize()=0;
};

#endif

//CConcrete.h

#ifndef CONCRETEH
#define CONCRETEH

#include "IInterface.h"

class CConcrete : public IInterface
{
public:
    CConcrete();
private:
    unsigned int getDataSize();
    unsigned int dataSize;
};

#endif

//CConcrete.cpp

#include "CConcrete.h"

CConcrete::CConcrete()
{
dataSize = 3;
}

unsigned int CConcrete::getDataSize()
{
return dataSize;
}

//main.cpp

#include "IInterface.h"
#include "CConcrete.h"
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
IInterface* interface = new CConcrete;
int w = interface->getDataSize();
std::cout<<"W: "<<w<<"\n";
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Are you able to boil this down to a [minimal test-case](http://sscce.org)?

Comment: Aside: Why are you implementing functions from the interface as `private`? Also, what happens with other compilers (e.g. VC++)?

Comment: Yes, it happens in a minimal case as well.

Comment: @Cameron: It separated the interface from the concrete class by forcing the user to use the interface. Updated answer with minimal test-case.

Comment: @Brian You misspelled the name of the `CConcrete` constructor as `Concrete` in the implementation. Otherwise, your test case compiles and runs fine in one file: http://ideone.com/kMlUT This makes me think that your file structure is wrong or that you are not giving the compiler the appropriate .cpp files on the command line.

Comment: I fixed that, it still gives "no function unsigned int getDataSize() in CConcrete" error.

Comment: @Brian your command line or file structure is messed up then. What is your command line?

Comment: BTW you are leaking memory in `main` (you never `delete` the object that you new-ed)

Comment: The comment says `Interface.h`, but the includes refer to `IInterface.h` (unless that is your issue and you do have a `IInterface.h` laying around, the code compiles and works as expected.

Comment: Mistakes were made in the test case, it works. I've no idea how to reproduce this then. Sorry!

Comment: @Brian: take a good night sleep, and tomorrow *read* the code as if you had not written it. It will probably jump out clear. If not, have someone else read the real code and double check. By not copying the exact code into the question you have probably not realized what the issue is and produced perfectly functioning code.

Comment: Ok, I will. It was copy pasted (the top code). The full code has tons of files, but I can't think of how to fix it. Is there a way to peek at the symbol table to see what it's pointing at?

Comment: teamhandbanana.com/ssyncd.tar.gz <-- Here is a link to the full source (with Makefile) if anybody can run a make clean && make to see if they have any issues with it. If you get the error I did, try to comment out the definition in CSerialData.cpp and run it.

Comment: With a few minor and apparently unrelated changes to get it to build (including IOid.h from CSerialData.cpp, for example), I got it to build and output 'W: 0'.

Comment: Fixed. There was a file "CSerialData.h.gch" that was causing updates to "CSerialData.h" to not take effect. Removing it fixed the issue. Thanks to everyone for their help!

Answer (score 0):

I compiled your code, after making a few small changes (to make it compile).  It runs fine on my machine.  I'm compiling on windows (minGW, in qt 4.70).  Here are the files, with changes.

```
//CConcrete.h

#ifndef CONCRETEH
#define CONCRETEH

#include "Interface.h"

class CConcrete : public IInterface
{
public:
    CConcrete();
private:
    unsigned int getDataSize();
    unsigned int dataSize;
};

#endif



//Interface.h

#ifndef INTERFACEH
#define INTERFACEH

class IInterface
{
public:
  IInterface();
  virtual ~IInterface(){}
    virtual unsigned int getDataSize()=0;
};

#endif



//CConcrete.cpp

#include "CConcrete.h"

CConcrete::CConcrete()
{
dataSize = 3;
}

unsigned int CConcrete::getDataSize()
{
return dataSize;
}


#include "Interface.h"

IInterface::IInterface()
{
}


#include "Interface.h"
#include "CConcrete.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

  IInterface* interface = new CConcrete;
  int w = interface->getDataSize();
  printf("%d", w);
  return 0;
}
```